# Run a script on server that creates an array (via php) that can be accessed later

Tags: php, arrays, server-side

I have an Icecast server (streaming internet radio) that I don't have full access to, and I can't change any of it's direct settings. All Icecast servers have a self-generated xml that displays current information about the stream (listeners, duration, stream name, and most importantly, current playing song title), however it does not have a way to show the last 5 or 10 tracks.

*[As an aside: there are ways to get this information, but it is either not handled correctly or the information is jumbled together with other information and is not easily accessible. Please do not focus on this part, as my question is about something else; I just wanted to give you the background of the question]*

I already have a PHP script that takes this xml file, and extracts the current song title. I want to create another PHP script that takes this song title and adds it to an array. It will run this script every 30 seconds, and add the current song title to the array. If the current song title and the first (the newest song is added to the "top" of the array) in the array match, no item is added (to avoid duplicate title as a result of songs being longer than 30 seconds). If the number of items reaches 11, the last item is dropped, to keep the array at 10.

With this array, I can then call on it at any time, and get a reliable source of the last 10 tracks.

My question is: How do I create an array via PHP that runs on it's own every 30 seconds, AND can be easily accessed via another PHP script? Or is there a better way to do this than PHP scripts? If so, please be detailed.

I know that MySQL is an option, but I'd rather avoid that, since it seems a bit like overkill for something like this. I am not also not that familiar working with MySQL.

I've seen some discussion about running a cron job regarding scheduling scripts on a server. I don't know if this is the best solution, but if it is, could you be more detailed and specific? I know nothing about cron.

**EDIT:** I'd like this array to be universal to all users, and not relative. The array can't exist within a single user's browser, but must be on the server.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a database, just save it to a file?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Comment: Furthermore, you can use the PHP `serialize` and `unserialize` methods to store PHP objects if you don't want to do something like XML. Just make sure not to let the file be visible to your end-users.

Comment: Yes though it might be easier to take familiar format that is suitable for text. Getting dangerously close to what the OP does not want us to talk about: you can even save it in XML format :)

Comment: I don't know about serialize/unserialize (is this like encoding a string? Does it hold information or is it just a method to protect it?), but I don't have a problem with XML.

If the solution is to ultimately create my own XML that is generated every 30 seconds, and conforms to the conditions expressed in my question, that would be fine. All I was originally stating about the XML generated by the Icecast server is that there is no way for me to affect it directly. I need to create something on my own that I have control over.

Comment: That said, I did think about that as an option, but I 1) don't know how I to dynamically create an XML file and 2) have it updated every 30 seconds without provocation from the user.

Answer (score -1):

Cron job is set to work programmatically on a server and it is not related to any client as it is. So that's not what you're looking for.

If I were you I would create a cookie and assign the current track data to it. This can be easily handled by Javascript. All you need to do is set a `setInterval` function to check whether it is the last track, if not, process the array in the cookie.

Comment: But this cookie would be relative to each user. Since all users are seeing the same set of tracks, I'd like the array to be universal. If it was done by cookie as you suggest, when a user begins, there will only be 1 track, and it will slowly grow over time. If it is universal, however, a new user would see the last 10, regardless if he/she was there yet.

Comment: It would be good, as you see, to have included this information in your post so that you would get better responses.